# Understanding Differences in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $x\in (A-B)^C$, what does this mean.

I think it means that $x \notin (A-B)$. In other words $x \in A^c $ and $x\notin B^c$.

Also if I have $x\in A^c -B^c$, does this mean that $x \in A^c$ and $x \notin B^c$. So that means that $x \notin A$ and $x \in B$.

It would help to see if my understanding of differences is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $x \notin A-B=\{ y|y \in A \land y \notin B \}$ means $x \notin A \lor x \in B.$ Notice that it is "or" rather than "and".

Second statement seems fine.